# Closed form for $K(n)=[0;\overline{1,2,3,...,n}]$

Tags: number-theory, closed-form, continued-fractions

I just started playing around with fairly simple periodic continued fractions, and I have a question. The fractions can be represented "linearly": for $n\in\Bbb N$,
$$K(n)=[0;\overline{1,2,3,...,n}]$$
I am seeking for a closed form for $K(n)$. I found the first few.

$n=1$:
$$K(1)=\frac1{1+K(1)}$$
$$\Rightarrow K(1)=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}2$$
$n=2$:
$$K(2)=\frac1{1+\frac1{2+K(2)}}$$
$$\Rightarrow K(2)=-1\pm\sqrt{3}$$
$n=3$:
$$K(3)=\frac1{1+\frac1{2+\frac1{3+K(3)}}}$$
$$\Rightarrow K(3)=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{37}}3$$
$n=4$:
$$K(4)=\frac1{1+\frac1{2+\frac1{3+\frac1{4+K(4)}}}}$$
$$\Rightarrow K(4)=\frac{-9\pm2\sqrt{39}}5$$
As you may be able to tell, these results are all found by simplifying the fraction until one has a quadratic in $K(n)$, at which point the quadratic formula may be applied.

I would be surprised if there wasn't a closed form expression for $K(n)$, as they can all be found the same way. I've failed to recognize any numerical patterns in the results, however.

So, I have two questions:

$1)$: How does one express $K(n)$ in the $\operatorname{K}_{i=i_1}^\infty \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ notation? I was thinking something like 
$$K(n)=\operatorname{K}_{i\geq0}\frac1{1+\operatorname{mod}(i,n)}$$
$2)$: What is a closed form for $K(n)$?

Thanks.

**Update:**

I'm pretty sure that all the $\pm$ signs in the beginning of the question should be changed to a $+$ sign.

Comment: An infinite continued fraction (as these are) has a unique value, so there really isn't a $\pm$ involved in the closed forms. Have you worked out those signs for the first few?

Comment: @coffeemath well, obviously, the fractions should all have positive values...

Comment: Have you tried looking at the coefficients in the functions $\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+\ddots \frac{1}{n+x}}}$ that are involved to see if there are any patterns there?  (Otherwise, it might turn out that the coefficients are just described by a recurrence relation without a nice known closed form solution.)

Comment: Computations on Wolfram Alpha give $K(5) = \frac{-195 + \sqrt{65\,029}}{86}$, $K(6) = \frac{-206 + 4\sqrt{4171}}{75}$, $K(7) = \frac{-4502 + \sqrt{29\,964\,677}}{1393}$, and $K(8) = \frac{-9280 + 3\sqrt{13\,493\,990}}{2494},$ which also don't seem to follow nice patterns.

Comment: @coffeemath based on Connor Harris's comment, I guess we can say that the signs would all be positive. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @DanielSchepler kind of, but I haven't tried super hard on that. Any resources you'd recommend for doing that sort of thing?

Comment: Using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents), you should be able to prove the coefficients involved in the equation are related to [A001040](http://oeis.org/A001040) and [A001053](http://oeis.org/A001053). Their values do not seem to have a simple closed form, but they can be expressed using hypergeometric functions.

Comment: @ConnorHarris How do you enter continued fractions like this into wolfram Alpha?

Comment: @clathratus For finite fractions, I think you just have to type the whole fraction out.

Comment: @clathratus Yes, in the few low cases I did, one choice led to a negative. In general they should be positive and less than $1.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up on Daniel Schepler's comment. Let $$P_n(x) = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{2 + \ddots \frac{1}{n+x}}}.$$ This is basically the RHS of the recurrence equation for $K(n)$. Then:
\begin{align*}
P_1(x) &= \frac{1}{x+1} \\
P_2(x) &= \frac{x+2}{x+3} \\
P_3(x) &= \frac{2x+7}{3x+10} \\
P_4(x) &= \frac{7x+30}{10x+43} \\
P_5(x) &= \frac{30x+157}{43x+225} \\
P_6(x) &= \frac{157x+972}{225x+1393}.
\end{align*}
Note that $P_n(x) = P_{n-1}\left( \frac{1}{x+n}\right)$. Therefore, if $P_{n-1}(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$, then
\begin{align*}P_n(x) &= \frac{\frac{a}{x+n} + b}{\frac{c}{x+n} + d} \\
&= \frac{bx + (a+bn)}{dx + (c+dn)}
\end{align*}
Thus in general, we may write $$P_n(x) = \frac{a_n x + a_{n+1}}{b_n x + b_{n+1}}$$
where $a$ and $b$ satisfy the recurrence $a_{n+1} = a_{n-1} + n a_n$ and likewise for $b$, with the initial conditions $a_1 = 0, a_2 = b_1 = b_2 = 1$. This recurrence gives the OEIS sequences linked by Jean-Claude Arbaut. $K(n)$ is a solution to $x - P_n(x) = 0$, or a root of the quadratic $$b_n x^2 + (b_{n+1} - a_n) x - a_{n+1} = 0.$$

Comment: Is the $a_n=a_{n-1}+na_n$ supposed to be $$a_n=a_{n-1}+na_{n-2}?$$

Comment: Thanks, fixed it

Comment: Excellent. Really great answer. Thank you!